# Javascript works locally, but no longer works when deployed to Heroku. (With turbo links.)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, production, turbolinks

For some reason my javascripts are not working on Heroku. I know that this has something to do with Turbolinks, but I'm not sure what could be causing it.

Gemfile:

```
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 1.3.0'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
```

As you can see, I am using the query-turbolinks gem. Locally, everything works, but when deployed all of my Javascript is broken as if I haven't loaded my javascripts correctly.

Maybe I need to apply this code to all of my javascripts?

```
var ready;
ready = function() {

  ...your javascript goes here...

};

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

I wonder why it is working in development but not in production...

Comment: I'm going to try pre-compiling my assets before I push to heroku. Maybe that is part of the issue.

Comment: I highly suggest to pre-compile (using `RAILS_ENV=production`), it allows you to catch errors before deployment and makes deployment on Heroku faster (Heroku will always recompile your assets at deploy time even if you didn't change any of them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with updating this in `production.rb`

```
config.assets.compile = true
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

Comment: config.serve_static_assets  is **config.serve_static_files** now/